# how to validate and prevent publish in netlify-cms with gatsby?

Tags: netlify-cms

I'm trying to add some validation in the netlify cms on the uploaded images, I want to check the extension of images to be one of ['png', 'jpg', 'jpag'], otherwise, I want to disable the publish button or showing any error message; I'm struggling with their docs and I can't find anything about validation except for strings types, any help would be  appreciated